# Angular - Binding the following data via ng-options for a select field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

Given the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/1102/

Suppose I received an ajax call with the following data I pass to a scope variable:

```
$scope.people_model = {  
   "people":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Jon"
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "name":"Adam"
      }
   ]
};
```

How would I work with the select box to iterate over the 'people' via ng-options?

```
<select 
  ng-options="p.name for name in people_model"
  ng-model="people_model">
</select>
```

Comment: I realize there are similar questions but I can't make the other answers work with the data structure for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your select as ,

```
 <select ng-model="currentSelected" ng-options="selection.id as selection.name for selection in people_model.people"></select>
```

You need to access the array **`people`** inside the object **`people_model`**

**`DEMO`**

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller("FirstCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.currentSelected = "1";
    $scope.people_model = {
      "people": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Jon"
      }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Adam"
      }]
    };

  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
  <select ng-model="currentSelected" ng-options="selection.id as selection.name for selection in people_model.people"></select>
</body>

</html>
```